# Interpolation of prefixes on @keyframes in Sass

Tags: sass

I'm trying to workaround [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) not supporting `@keyframe` by generating my own prefixes version with a Sass loop like this:

```
$list: '' -ms- -webkit- -moz- -o-
$at: @  //at sign
@each $prefix in $list

  #{$at}#{$prefix}keyframes moveclouds
    from
      #{$prefix}transform: translateX(2400px)
    to
      #{$prefix}transform: translateX(-400px)
```

and expecting to generate css:

```
@keyframes moveclouds from {
  transform: translateX(2400px);
}
@keyframes moveclouds to {
  transform: translateX(-400px);
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds from {
  -moz-transform: translateX(2400px);
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds to {
  -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
}
....
```

the issue is that I cannot figure out how to force Sass output `@` (at sign) in start of a line

if I do

```
$at: @    // wont work, error
$at: \@   // will generate  \@keyframes = not good
$at: "\@" // wont work error
$at: @@   // will generate  @@keyframes = not good
```

so anyone got an idea how to output at sign in Sass ?

Comment: Does the error have a message?

Comment: Looks like this has now been fixed. I ran into the same issue but updated to 3.4.13 and the error is gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This simply isn't possible using variable interpolation.  You can get around the `@` assignment like this:

```
$at: unquote("@"); // either of these will work
$amp: #{"@"};
```

But then you end up with this error:

> error sass/test.scss (Line 4: Invalid CSS after "": expected  selector_comma_sequence, was "@-ms-keyframes ...")

Interpolation on `@keyframes` is not currently supported, but will be in the future.  You can [track the progress of that on GitHub](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/429).  In the mean time, you'll have to write out your keyframe information by hand.  A simple example looks like this:

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }

    @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@include keyframes(foo) {
    0% {
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

A more complex example can be found in [Eric Meyer's Sass Animation library](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation/blob/master/stylesheets/animation/_core.scss).

Comment: thx anyway for trying, I didn't know that unquote function exist in Sass :) ... tried it as you propose, doh like you said it blow up. I'm using manually written keyframes prefixes myself, but the fact that it cannot be written "prettier" is a thing that annoy me (and will probably keep me awake tonight)

Comment: I came across a discussion from a year ago on Google groups regarding animations, hinting at better support for it.  I'm guessing their solution was the `@content` directive.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sass-lang/MfPZyWRRPZk

Comment: sadly, Cimmanon is right, this isn't possible :(   ...this is like a child's disappointing when he see his superhero in girls outfit :)