# @content VS normal additional rules

Tags: css, sass, mixins

What is the difference between doing:

```
@mixin test($color: #000) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: $color;
}

@mixin extension($color: #000) {
    @include test($color);
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

or doing the following?

```
@mixin test($color: #000) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: $color;

    @content
}

@mixin extension($color: #000) {
    @include test($color) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
}
```

is there any difference in the resulting CSS?

I cannot see the convenience of the *@content* directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@content` directive allows you to have a selector inside of your mixin and inject specific styles within that selector.  The most common use case is a media query:

```
@mixin bp($i) {
    @media (min-width: $i) {
        @content;
    }
}

.foo {
    color: red;

    @include bp(30em) {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Other popular uses include abstracting [keyframes declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076063/interpolation-of-prefixes-on-keyframes-in-sass), [placeholder selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181849/placeholder-mixin-scss-css), or other selectors that require prefixes.